# add data from json in non template page with angularjs

Tags: angularjs, json

I have static page with articles and I would like to fill number of likes for each article from json with angularjs. Is that posible or do I need to load whole page as template and fill all the detail with ng-repeat?

Is there something like

```
$("#like id" + i).val(jsonarray[i])
```

for angularjs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign the array to the scope and use the interpolation `{{ }}` and `ng-repeat` in the HTML

JS Controller:

```
$scope.jsonarray = jsonarray;
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="value in jsonarray">{{value}}</div>
```

Or:

```
<div id="like">{{jsonarray[0]}}</div>
```

Comment: But if I have fixed html with different divs that need value from json. This will only repeat this one div.

Comment: @stefansixx1 You don't have to use `ng-repeat`, you can use `{{ }}` braces at any point to display expressions or scope variables.